# Do I have to re-register a client script on post-back?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, postback, registerclientscriptblock

If I am adding a client-script block on the first page load like this:

```
   if (this.Page.IsPostBack==false)
            {
                if (this.Page.ClientScript
                          .IsClientScriptIncludeRegistered("ctlmyControl")==false)
                {
                    string guidParamToHackBrowserCaching 
                                  = System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

this.Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptInclude("ctlmyControl"
                         , ResolveUrl(String
                          .Format("~/clientScripts/ctlmyControl.js
                        ?par={0}",guidParamToHackBrowserCaching)));
                }
            }
```

Do I need to **re-register** it on all the post-backs?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the actual part of the page where the script resides is re-rendered after a postback, then yes. If not, then no, and in fact, you *must not* or it could be duplicated.

More specifically, if you're using a page that uses partial postbacks, and the code that renders the `UpdatePanel` needs to register scripts, then you *should not* re-register it except on the first page load. On the other hand, if the page is loaded on a full postback, or initial page load, then you *must* register it.  `ScriptManager` will insert scripts outside the dynamic content area of an `UpdatePanel` on partial postbacks, but it will not account for existing scripts that may have been rendered there on previous postbacks. (Does this make sense? Not really. But there it is.)

The long and short if it is that scripts are not persisted in any way, except to the extent that they're still present at the client because that part of the page didn't get reloaded. And `ScriptManager` doesn't make any effort to remember what's already been rendered in the static part of a page. So if the actual place where the script will be rendered is going to get updated on a postback (be it async or full) then you need to re-register the script, otherwise, do not.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what the script is for, but probably.  When you post back, the old DOM in the browser, including any scripts, is destroyed, and you're also working with a new page instance.  If you still need this as part of the page, then you need to make sure it's still registered.

An alternate approach is to refactor the script to be more static, such that the control value you need is a passed a parameter to a function.  Then you can just use a normal `<script` tag, and the only thing you need to do on each postback is write the id of the control to a variable that you can use when calling the function.

Comment: If it is an async call to server -partial postback- I think the script stays in the browwser cache. Correct?

Comment: @burak - yes, for partial postbacks the DOM in the browser is not destroyed, and so the script will still exist at the client.

Comment: .. unless the script was actually rendered in the part of the page that got updated. I am pretty sure if you use `RegisterStartupScript` it will be in the `UpdatePanel` area, and if not, it will not be. So you would want to re-register a startup script after a partial postback (and really that's the distinction, because such a script will actually run after a partial postback).